# How to quantitatively measure the diversity of a set of images

Tags: image, machine-learning, image-processing, statistics, computer-vision

I'm trying to measure the diversity of a set of images. I'm defining *diversity* as a qualitative measure of the overall amount of *difference* in a set of images, so a set of identical images has a diversity of 0.

So far, the approach I thought of is to take the average intensity of every pixel in the set, that will give an "average" image for the set. Then use the pixels in the "average" image to calculate the standard deviation for intensity of every pixel, creating a matrix of standard deviation values for every pixel. Then I can take the matrix norm of the standard deviation matrix- larger norms imply more diversity.

Another post (linked below) suggests that, to measure how closely an image is to a set of image, one can create a classifier and see with what tolerance value the new image can be accepted. This measures how closely one image matches a set of images, and doesn't measure the diversity of the set (unless it's performed many times, but I'm not sure how that would work).

Is there a better way of measuring the diversity of a set of images than just by taking the matrix norm of the standard deviation of every pixel? Any info is appreciated. Thank you!

Posts referenced:

[Measuring how a new sample contributes to the diversity of a dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55365075/measuring-how-a-new-sample-contributes-to-the-diversity-of-a-dataset)

[Clustering of images to evaluate diversity (Weka?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34771880/clustering-of-images-to-evaluate-diversity-weka)

Comment: it depends on your dataset. if all images are from the same scene, averaging the pixels value of images give you a estimation of the background, and variance (with some conditon) is changes in the scene. is it the case?

Comment: @Masoud not entirely sure what you mean by "scene", but all images in a set will be drawings of an object. One set might have many images of butterflies, another set may have airplanes, etc. Do you think the variance is the best way to measure the diversity?

Comment: for a single scene, you can imagine a fixed camera recording video. for your case, not at all. suppose you have two images of a single butterfly, but with a slight translation, and the background is complicated. while you have images of a single object, variance between them is so high. so please consider AI techniques for the case.

Comment: That's a good explanation - two images that are mere translations of another may have very high pixel-by-pixel variance, when in fact they seem very similar through visual inspection. Thanks for the insight.